# LDAP Authentication not enforced with certain URLs running websvn

Tags: svn, directory, apache2, ldap, websvn

I am running a Apache server (2.2.21) on my 32-bit Win7 desktop with a WebSVN 2.3.3 and Subversion 1.5.6.

Here's the problem :

If i were to navigate to `http://myservername/websvn`, LDAP auth will be enforced and only the users whom i allow in the config file can access it.
However, if i were to navigate to `http://myservername/WebSvn` or `/Websvn` or even `/webSVN`, you get the idea, LDAP auth is not enforced and they allow any users, even those not specified in the config file, to enter the same websvn page.

So, how do i go about resolving this issue ?

Update :
Here's my websvn.conf file. For security reasons, i have altered it to fit the post here.
This particular file is called in the `httpd.conf` file by inserting the '`Include C:/somehwere/websvn.conf`' near the end of the file.

```
<Location /websvn/> 
    #Redirect any requests to this page to the listing.php
    FallbackResource listing.php

    AuthLDAPBindDN "acct@xxx.com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "password"

    #The LDAP query URL
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://x.x.x.x.x.x:389/DC=x,DC=x,DC=x,DC=x,DC=x?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user)" NONE

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Websvn"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off  

    AuthUserFile /dev/null          
    Require ldap-user user1

</Location>
```

Update 7/2/2013 :
I was informed that  should be used instead of  and i have done that.
The Apache [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html) details the difference between  and  especially under the part, "What to use when". So, i modified the websvn.conv file to reflect this :

```
<Directory /websvn> 
        DirectoryIndex listing.php

        Options FollowSymLinks

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        AuthLDAPBindDN "acct@xxx.com"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "password"

        #The LDAP query URL
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://x.x.x.x.x.x:389/DC=x,DC=x,DC=x,DC=x,DC=x?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user)" NONE

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Websvn"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off  

        Require ldap-user user1 
    </Directory>
```

However, i still can access my websvn even with the incorrect URL, eg./websVn and furthermore, the authentication does not kick in anymore.

Also, the page listing.php does not show. Instead, the directory listing of websvn is shown.

Can anyone please point out to me what am i doing wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: does the context is applied to virtual host or directory. if the context is being applied to directory or virtual host then only this directorywill inforced by ldap. if you can put how did you confogure ldap auth it will give better understanding of your situation

Comment: Hi Saddam Abu Ghaida, my apologies. I have included my websvn.conf file

Comment: I am still facing this issue...i may have to use the Rewrite function to take care of this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by converting all incoming URL to lowercase with this line of code in my httpd.conf file.

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
   RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

For the LDAP auth to work too, i had to use the < Location > version of the websvn config file.

However, i am still puzzled as to why < Directory > does not handle case sensitivity even though Apache docs claims it does.

Comment: So, i just found out that the above will generate another problem.
You will not have any problems checking out but when you commit a file, you will get an error something along this line, "Repository moved permanently to ‘…’; please relocate".

If you were to navigate to your repo thru a web browser, you will find that you not be able to go to folders or open files that has capital letters.

Hence, i had to revert everything back and live with websvn being accessbile thru the url with different alphabetical casings.